# How Does gcc on Solaris Find Its Libraries?

Tags: gcc, makefile, solaris, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install 'quadrupel', a library that relies on ffmpeg on Solaris x86.

I managed to build ffmpeg and its libraries live in /opt/gnu/lib and the includes are in /opt/gnu/include but when I try to build quadrupel, it can't find the ffmpeg headers.

What flags/configuration is required to include those two directories in the proper search paths for libraries and includes? I'm not much of a Makefile hacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the path by setting the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  However I would suggest changing the system paths as well so you don't have to change the library path for all users.  This can be done using crel.

```
crle -l -c /var/ld/ld.config -l /usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/opt/gnu/lib
```

For the includes just add -I/opt/gnu/include to your CFLAGS variable.

Comment: That should be crle (configure runtime linking environment)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to add the following to the Makefile:

```
CFLAGS  += -I/opt/gnu/include
LDFLAGS += -L/opt/gnu/lib -R/opt/gnu/lib
```

The -I argument tell gcc where to find the include files. The -L flag tells ld where to find the libraries while linking. The -R flag writes /opt/gnu/lib into the library search path in the quadrupel binary, so it can find its libraries when it starts.